# Allure integration with multi-module test suite

Tags: java, xml, maven, testng, allure

We have an test suite which is based on maven framework and consists of multi-module. Modules used -

- `project` [no code]
- `test` [`@Test` classes are included under */src/main/java*, `testng.xml` in */src/main/resources*]
- `core` [configured to execute basic utilities for environment setup]
- `driver` [configures test buckets and modulates report generation using testng]

Trying to integrate the [report generation using allure](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/TestNG), I've added the following to the ***project*** `pom.xml` -

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-deploy-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Also the dependencies for the same to the ***test*** `pom.xml` as -

```
<!--allure related dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.16</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-java-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.RC2</version>
        </dependency>
```

> ***Step 1*** - After executing the tests `mvn exec:java -pl driver` I can see a ***/target/allure-results*** folder generated.
>
> ***Step 2*** - `mvn jetty:run` reads Started Jetty Server
>
> ***Step 3*** - But when I go to localhost:8080 on my browser it just has a heading
>
> ***Directory :/***

***Question***

- I doubt the path specified by me is incorrect somewhere so jetty is unable to locate the reports, but couldn't figure out where. Is it for the tests that are executed or for the `testng.xml` in resources? 
  Or do I need to correct the path somewhere in the pom only?
- Also is the way I am trying to use the dependencies(in parent `project` pom) correct?

---

***Update 1***

The exec configuration used is as follows -

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.driver.Driver</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Appreciate any response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many open points on this question which are not clear due to lack of details.

According to your description the project structure is hence as following:

```
project
  |
  |--- test-module
  |--- core-module
  |--- driver-module (depends on `core` and `test`)
  |
   \ pom.xml
```

You actually execute tests only via the `driver` module and via the `exec-maven-plugin`, however the [allure](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/TestNG) documentation specifies the classic approach, to execute the [`test`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) phase, that is, the Maven phase dedicated to tests execution (via the `maven-surefire-plugin`, automatically invoked by Maven during this phase via [default bindings](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html)).

You actually configure the `maven-surefire-plugin` as specified by its documentation: specifying it into the parent `pom.xml` file would be fine in this case, in its `pluginManagement` section > Maven will pick up its global configuration during the `default-test` execution of the default `maven-surefire-plugin` binding.

However, the whole mechanism is linked to the `test` phase. Do you execute it?

You did not provide details about the `exec-maven-plugin` and what it is supposed to do concerning the `driver` module and why you would use the `jetty-maven-plugin` to see the report. Normally, test reports are available and can be seen direct `html` files, no need to host them in an embedded jetty server, unless required by the overall process (CI, deployment to a company server, etc.). These reports should also be made available to the project documentation site, which can be generated via the `site` lifecycle and its [`maven-site-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/).

From your details, you share the `jetty-maven-plugin` configuration pointing at a `site` folder: is this folder generated during the `test` phase (if you invoke it)? Or during your `exec` invocation?

Concerning the way you use dependencies in the parent pom, you actually did not share it in your question, so not easy to help. Normally, you would put dependencies in the `dependencies` section of the parent pom which are common to all modules (e.g. classic example is `log4j`, something every module would use). Otherwise, you would use the `dependencyManagement` section of the parent pom to manage versions of certain dependencies which could be use by one or more modules (but modules would need to re-declare them to effectively use them, omitting their versions though, specified by the parent). That is, the parent pom is a central place of governance and harmonisation.

---

**Update**

Concerning the `/target/allure-results` folder generated, you need also to check its content to be a valid site directory (that is, e.g. it should contain an `index.html`).

Creating a new Maven webapp project and adding the following to its `pom.xml` file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

(Note: exactly as per your question, but pointing simply to the `site` directory)

And executing:

```
mvn clean install site
mvn jetty:run
```

the Maven site (generated during the `site` phase as invoked above) would be available at `localhost:8080` (default jetty URL). That's because an `index.html` was generated.

However, if I manually delete the `index.html`, the jetty will show an `Directory: /` page, listing the available files.

Hence, most probably, the allure report didn't generate an `index.html` file, because most probably it is not meant to generate it, but simply an HTML report generared during the `test` phase.

Comment: 1. No, we do not execute tests using `mvn clean test`
2. We would like to use the reports for CI hence jetty as of now, but if there is an alternate, please do share.
3. Already mentioned "I can see a /target/allure-results folder generated." after `mvn exec..` in step1.
4. We are using `dependencies` in pom specific to modules, just the plugins using `pluginManagement` in parent pom.

Comment: @nullpointer check my update about the jetty error, I was able to replicate it. Concerning the `exec` configuration, is it similar to [the one reported here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/master/allure-report-preview/pom.xml)?

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem I have posted. Multi module and mvn exec:java is something in a combination that I am looking for and trying further to dig in. though your answer. No doubts the info shared in the answer is helpful to helps understand a lot about implementing allure report and jetty and get into a direction to implement it as such and the reward bounty is deserved as well.

Comment: @nullpointer unfortunately the problem you posted didn't have enough details (again, the exec configuration was not provided). So it's difficult to provide support. What are you trying to achieve with exec plugin exactly? I fear you getting in a difficult path away from standard Maven practices. Concerning the bounty, just to clarify: you did not award it, the system did automatically thanks to the 2 upvotes and as unique answer, otherwise it would not have been awarded (that is, wasted).

Comment: updated the post with exec details. what we are trying to achieve in straightforward words is " to execute tests inside a module using exec phase and get allure reports generated for the test results."

Comment: @nullpointer and indeed that's not a standard practice, because you would skip the `maven-surefire-plugin` execution doing so and as such skip also the allure configuration as per its official documentation. You would then only rely on the Java API of allure, hence it really depends on what the `com.driver.Driver` is doing (again, not enough details :)).